# Non-JS fallback for Dropdown Menu that goes to a URL on submit

Tags: javascript, onsubmit, fallback

I currently have a dropdown menu that will direct the user to different URLs based on what they have selected. However, when I disable javascript and select items from the dropdown, the user remains on the same page. What is the best way to handle this for users who have JS disabled?

Comment: Generally very few users have JS disabled. Are you sure it's worth the added complexity?

Comment: when you say drop-down menu, you mean a form <select> element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `onsubmit` tag you included, I will assume you are using a `<select>` menu. Without JavaScript, you need either a different element, like a CSS-based dropdown menu with actual links, or a server-side solution to accept the form submission and redirect to the URL of the selected item, if the URL is in the value.